# How do create with NodeJS Microsoft Office / Open Office / PDF / thumbnails?

Tags: node.js, ms-office, thumbnails, openoffice.org

Does exists any way to generate image thumbnails for Microsoft Office, Open Office, PDF's and another most frequently used files/documents?

Server side of my app is running on NodeJS.

Thanks a lot for an each help.